# extracting few cases from part of json

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json:

```
items = "[
{"prop1":"here","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","prop3b":"here"},
{"prop1":"pole","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"there ","excludeDomains":"asteroid","prop3b":"pole"},
{"prop1":"orcsstar","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","excludeDomains":"dwarves","prop3b":"orcsstar"},
{"prop1":"guntham","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","prop3b":"gunther"},
{"prop1":"depot","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","prop3b":"depot"},
{"prop1":"department","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"dept","prop3b":"depart"}
]"
```

so i have 6 entries here stored in var items.
How do i get only 4 entries out of this.
I tried slice, but it doesnt separate well on '{}' braces. or [], present at start, please help me select this subarray of 4 entries enclosed in {}.

Comment: 1) That's not valid syntax because you have mismatched `"`'s. 2) If it's JSON, you need to `JSON.parse` it first. `var items = JSON.parse(dataString)`. After that' you'll have an array that you can use `slice` on.

Answer (score 1):

Slice works fine here once you correct outer quotes

```js
items = '[{"prop1":"here","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","prop3b":"here"},{"prop1":"pole","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"there","excludeDomains":"asteroid","prop3b":"pole"},{"prop1":"orcsstar","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","excludeDomains":"dwarves","prop3b":"orcsstar"},{"prop1":"guntham","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","prop3b":"gunther"},{"prop1":"depot","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"","prop3b":"depot"},{"prop1":"department","prop2":"all","contentType":"All","dateRangeType":"Anytime","excludeWords":"dept","prop3b":"depart"}]'


var parsedAndSlicedAndStringified = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(items).slice(0,4), null, 4);

document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = parsedAndSlicedAndStringified ;;
```

```html
<pre id="pre">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be kept as an object `JSON.parse(items)` as opposed to a string and use a library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to search through the object for the items you want or simply `.slice(0,3)` to get the first 4. If needed to be back in a string `JSON.stringify()` the result of above.

First 4 items in full JS:

`JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(items).slice(0,3))`